# Can't seem to upload a file to a custom directory

Tags: uploads

I am trying to do something extremely simple.

I just want to save a file, in a custom wordpress upload directory inside of the media library.

But it just won't work.

I've tried the solution here, but it just times out.  I get a 110 connection timed out.

I've tried using several functions such as wp_upload_bits, wp_handle_upload, and other ones.

Comment: Can you show the code you used?

Comment: You have to write a function to change the uploads path  for temporary change than once the upload is done you should remove it. If you can write a function for the uploads directory.  There are some existing similar questions available.  Find it for better answer

Comment: I tried the change uploads directory trick, but for some reason I get a connection timed out.

I'm trying a couple of things today but it seems as if I need my own custom function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins available for media management and file management which will allow you to specify where you want uploaded files to go based on user or other requirements.

https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=ssl&ei=lY5zVprEJuSD8QeMkJ7gAw#q=wordpress+plugin+file+manager

https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=ssl&ei=lY5zVprEJuSD8QeMkJ7gAw#q=wordpress+plugin+media+manager

There are also upload manager plugins:

https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=ssl&ei=lY5zVprEJuSD8QeMkJ7gAw#q=wordpress+plugin+upload+manager